# Faster relay? 5, 12 or 24V?

Tags: relay, inductance

I'm in a pursuit of finding the fastest PCB relay there is and there is a Chinese manufacturer that produces DPDT PCB relays that are rated 5V, 12V and 24V. 
Which of these would have the fastest switching time? Can you conclude that without doing a measurement? (cause, you know, the shipping takes like 3 weeks or so...)
I'd argue that higher voltage rated relays would contain more windings, therefore would take more time to magnetize up to the switching point.

P.S. knowing the "problem-solving mentality" of the SO folk, I do not want to switch to a SS-Relay or transistor, I am building a highly useless thing called a relay CPU :)

Edit1: thank you for all the comments. Usually, cheap chinese manufacturers don't provide useful datasheets at all. And buying more expensive relays can get really expensive quite fast. But still, thank you all for infos :)

Comment: why not check the specsheet?

Comment: Although giving an individual relay more coil voltage will make it activate faster, there is no direct correlation between coil voltage and relay activation between models. If you want fast you need to search through spec sheets.

Comment: the voltage of the relay doesn't directly say anything about its speed. However, anyone who produces relays and is worthy of your money will have characterized the relays they sell and will give you a datasheet. No info from the manufacturer, no business. It's really as simple as that.

Comment: For some reason I have a feeling the switching time is not going to be your bottleneck...

Comment: @Trevor but it's current that creates the magnetic force that actuates the contact. If the coil resistance is scaled to the voltage that just ends up being a wash.

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes I meant if you apply more V to the relay in your hand... it will be faster. BUt that is the only correlation you can state accurately.

Comment: Never hurts to get this documented on a question like this. http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/index.html

Comment: "I'd argue that higher voltage rated relays would contain more windings" ... more likely the same number of windings and thinner wire ...

Comment: @jonk those are so cool

Comment: Or this: https://hackaday.com/2012/01/16/the-tim-8-is-the-smallest-8-bit-relay-computer-ever/

Comment: @Trevor Yes, they are!! Luckily, PSU is just a few miles away from me. hehe. (I used to teach there.)

Comment: The OP needs to define "mechanical" for us. Does it include a reed relay, for example?

Comment: Here's another technology: https://flipdots.com/en/products-services/small-7-segment-displays/ (15 ms switching time, though [compare with \$500\:\mu\textrm{s}\$ for a fast reed relay.]) Might look "really cool" for a relay computer to also make the state of a relay visible like this. They may large displays out of these relay bits. Boggles the imagination.

Comment: Harry used 4PDT relays for his computer (for good reason.) I don't know of anything faster, mechanically, than a reed relay. But finding 4PDT reed relays will be both "expensive" as well as tricky. Given the number needed, I'd probably try contacting Hasco, Coto, Pickering, and anyone else I could think of and just ask them to make some specials. Either that, or I'd get good at making the things myself by winding my own coils around a bunch of "make" or "changeover" glass reed relay ampules. (I have drawers of them here, used back in the day for keyboards.)

Comment: The most reliable fast, inexpensive relays will be Telecom types gold plated contacts in the <2A category. RC coupled current limiting from a higher voltage will accelerate the speed with over voltage and settle at lower power with under voltage since there is a wide hysteresis range.

Comment: But you cannot spec Fast and Cheap  and 4P2T.  Pick any 1  spec... or look at https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/standex-meder-electronics/DIL05-2C90-63L/374-1323-ND/3131683  2P2T Operate Time 0.7ms 
Release Time 1.5ms

Comment: @Trevor: "*... more likely the same number of windings and thinner wire ...*". No, the ampere turns would have to be constant for different voltage versions of the same relay so turns go up as resistance goes up. See Spehro's succinct answer.

Comment: @Transistor yes I realize that, however, thinner wire with more voltage keeps the ampere turns the same. IE. to have the same I with more V you need more R.

Comment: @Trevor: But you don't want the same I. You want less I as V goes up. \$ I = \frac {P}{V} \$ where \$ P \$ stays constant. I know you know all this. There's just something strange happening between your brain and your fingers!

Comment: @Transistor :) you're right I forgot about power... duh...

Comment: @Transistor... my confusion was.. I thought there was nothing in the OPs question that implied Vendor A's 5V relay is the same power as Vendor B's 24V model. Rereading, it implies the same basic model family, so yes I would assume powers to be close to equal.

Comment: I am not sure how the question offended someone so much for a downvote, but whatever... :)

Comment: Faster does not necessarily mean better... you have to factor in contact bounce too. Making the thing slap harder may mean it bounces longer so you end up further behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that ampere-turns is constant for the same force, so the number of turns n must be proportional to the reciprocal of the nominal coil current. The inductance is proportional to n^2.

We can also see that coil power is generally constant for a given design of relay, across coil voltage ratings. So the coil resistance must increase with the nominal voltage squared.

The effect of the inductance is a time constant L/R. Since L and R both increase with the square of nominal coil voltage rating, there is no first order effect on the inductance-delayed rise of force. Of course there is inertia in the moving parts and the delay due to the mechanical parts moving will not change with coil voltage rating.

If you look at data sheets from reputable makers such as Panasonic you will see the same max/nominal operate times stated across coil voltages.

For those who want to get an intuitive feel for this, the wire is thinner, there are more turns, and it fills about the same volume on the bobbin.

---

---

The release time is generally stated to be lower than the operate time, but take care that this is usually specified without a flyback diode- which will greatly increase the release time.

Comment: If one really wanted to activate fast, perhaps a trick from the stepper motor world could be borrowed: choose a low voltage coil, but implement a high voltage driver to overcome the inductance, with chopping current control to keep from then burning out the coil.  But really fast applications might consider solid state switching, if possible.

Comment: +1 for complete answer. Pretty sure the mechanical inertia will be orders of magnitude longer then inductive delays anyway.

Comment: @Trevor It's a little complicated- the inductance which I referred to (for simplicity) above as if it was a constant is not really constant- it varies as the relay clapper moves and closes or opens  the magnetic circuit. During drop-out the inductance drops rapidly as the clapper leaves the pole piece, causing the  coil current to increase just as the spring in the contacts is being released, assuming a flyback diode, further slowing the drop-out. I think you're right in that the inductance is much less of an effect on the **operate** (pull-in) time than the mechanical inertia.